# Errorhandler in Camel Route retrying more times than configured value

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have set up a test case where I expect a message to go to a dead letter channel after an exception occurs, retrying 2 times to process it:

```
public class TestObjectRoutes extends SpringRouteBuilder {
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void configure() {
        errorHandler(transactionErrorHandler().logHandled(true)
                .onRedelivery(exchange -> System.out.println("Testing..."))
                .maximumRedeliveries(2));

        from("activemq:queueone")
                .transacted()
                .to("activemq:queuetwo")
                .process(javaThrower); // This line throws an exception
        ;
    }
}
```

After calling the route I can see the following:

```
Testing...
Testing...

2016-03-17 15:59:32.762 ERROR 3296 --- [testobject.one]] o.a.camel.processor.DeadLetterChannel    : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:DESKTOP-HRMD8N6-64204-1458226711533-21:2:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-HRMD8N6-64190-1458226703758-0-8). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 3 caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JAVA EXCEPTION. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[sendTo(Endpoint[activemq://mydeadletterchannel] InOnly)]
```

Which looks exactly like what I was expecting.

The only problem is that it does not stop there. It keeps retrying the call and I see these 2 log lines and the ERROR **7** times

Then it moves the message to a DLQ, however, it is not the DLQ queue name I defined but it's moved to "ACTIVEMQ.DLQ".

This makes me think that somewhere else another default configuration is taking over but I can't seem to pinpoint it.

This is my ActiveMQComponent configuration:

```
@Autowired
private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {

    ActiveMQComponent component = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
    component.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
    component.setTransacted(true);

    camelContext.addComponent("activemq", component);
}
```

Does anyone know why this behaviour happens?

Edit:

After adding a custom connection factory my code looks like this:

```
ActiveMQComponent component = ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
    component.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);
    component.setTransacted(true);

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(0);
    connectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
    connectionFactory.setBrokerURL("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
    component.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    camelContext.addComponent("activemq", component);
```

Comment: How have you configured your activemq component?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried setting the redelivery policy on the connection factory? I believe you're setting the redelivery policy for Camel and not changing the redelivery for ActiveMQ

Comment: I'm trying to but I can't find an example of how to configure it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default retry/redelivery for camel-jms is 6 so that's why you're getting the 2 messages and the error 7 times.

Use the connection factory creator method from the [camel-jms tests](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jms/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jms/CamelJmsTestHelper.java) createConnectionFactory() specifying that maximum redeliveries you want and pass this connection factory into your camel component. If using spring then the [transactional client docs](http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html) has come examples of building connection factories and ActiveMQComponents, you'll just need to add a redelivery policy bean to the connection factory bean.

There are other good examples of using transactions and configuring redelivery of JMS messages in the camel-jms component tests.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to look in the camel-jms tests. I have found the correct way to set up the connection factory there. I have not yet found where I can configure the name of the default queue "ACTIVEMQ.DLQ". Any ideas?

Comment: I can't tell from the code you posted how you've configured the message to be sent to your custom DLQ so far but this page on [message redelivery and dlq handling](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) says that the DLQ needs to be configured in the activemq.xml of your broker